# Django Models outside of app directory migration not available

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-apps

My models have been placed outside (as same level) of my `Django` app. Everything works fine, but when I run in my terminal:

> $ python manage.py makemigrations

it returns:

> $ No changes detected

my project tree is same as bellow:

Project

```
|_ app
  |_ migrations
  |_ admin.py
  .
  .
  .
  |_ models.py
  |_ urls.py
  |_ views.py
|_config
  |_ settings.py
  |_ urls.py
  |_ wsgi.py
|_core
  |_ MyModel.py
```

I have just separated models outside of my app `directory`. How to add changes in `MyModel.py` to support migration?

Comment: you might be looking for this https://williamsbdev.com/posts/django-models-directory/

Comment: I'm using DJango 1.10.2

Comment: not working showing error at console:
~/project/app/api/views/serializer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from core.AllUsers.UserSerializer import UserSerializer
ImportError: No module named GroupSerializer @jayeshjodhawat

Comment: try - `from core.MyModel import *` in app/models.py insted of previous one

Comment: after that, in my views I have done: from .models import UserSerializer

`UserSerializer` is red marked underlined and says:
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Comment: notice that my model is under core, which is as same level as where is app

Comment: Have you add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: yes I did @EdwinLunando